# What fonts does stack overflow use?

Tags: discussion

What fonts does stack overflow use? Why were they chosen?

I find that there is often a lot of thought put into things like this, which is why I ask.

Answer (score 21):

Let's go meta, on meta. Development tools tell all:

In Chrome

1. Right click on a word
2. Click *"Inspect element".*
3. Make sure *"Show inherited properties"* is checked.

[image: Development tools]

```
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-kerning: auto;
font-size: 24px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-weight: normal;
```

Answer (score 12):

What [Evan Carroll](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286313/5832912) said. But this is not easy for a layman. So I suggest an alternative here. There's an extension for Chrome called [WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en), which makes things easier.

## [WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en)

> What is the easiest way to find out the fonts used in a webpage? Firebug and Webkit Inspector are easy enough to use for developers. However, for others, this should not be necessary. **With this extension, you could inspect web fonts by just hovering on them.** It is that simple and elegant.
>
> It also detects the services used for serving the web fonts. Supports Typekit and Google Font API.
>
> *Recommended by Wired WebMonkey, Lifehacker, and SwissMiss.*

Comment: Good thing Stack Overflow is not made for laymen but for professional and enthusiast programmers :-)

Comment: @EvanCarroll Well.. Thanks. Not everyone googling "what fonts do a website use" follow the developer-level steps. I just thought I could help those laymen, not that I am one, btw. :) Also, if you read my earlier comments, you'll know that I already agree mine is inferior.

Comment: I would advise against this, unless you trust http://www.chengyinliu.com/ to read and change all your data one very website. With a project that doesn't have a public source repo that I see. the repo link on http://www.chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html to https://github.com/willow/WhatFont-Bookmarklet is broke