# Negative question scores should be prefixed with a − (minus sign) instead of a - (hyphen)

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design

Right now, a negative question/answer score is prefixed with a dash (U+002D). It should be prefixed with a minus sign (U+2212) instead, which is the typographically correct character. The minus sign has the HTML4 named entity `&minus;`, so its availability should be good. Here is a visual comparison:

> -4 (dash)
>   −4 (minus sign)
>   +4 (plus sign, for reference)

Side by side comparison:

[image: Minus sign side by side comparison]

Comment: This is ultimately going to be down to taste. To me, the typographically incorrect character looks much better - it's much smaller. The correct character is way too big.

Comment: What about [U+002B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b/index.htm) for the Plus sign as well? Although I don't think there is a visual difference in this case; it'd be just pedantic.

Comment: @Tunaki: Is that not what's already in use (in places where the positive sign actually matters anyway)?

Comment: Literally nitpicking though.

Comment: What makes a minus 'too big' when a plus in the same position is not? In most fonts, the minus is exactly as wide as the plus sign *by design*, to avoid a jarring jump when there is a +x above a -x. By that token, an adjustment of the size of the `+` character to make it as narrow as the `-` should work as well. Not so: the stem widths would be different.

Comment: If screen readers are reading the post score as "dash 4" instead of "minus 4" or "negative 4", then it should be changed.

Comment: This particular issue aside, I'm curious how a screen reader would fare against the site in general.

Comment: Doing this also lines up the number better. I think it's a good idea.

Comment: `-` has been used as a minus sign since before I don't know what. It _is_ a minus sign. Actually, it is _the_ minus sign. If y

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy No, what you mentioned is U+0045, called the [*hyphen-minus*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm)

Comment: Which character is used is of significance to folks using screen readers. Not all programmers can see the relative sizes of the glyphs.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: Emphasised differently: `-` is *a* minus sign.

Comment: @BSMP Testing with **NVDA ver. 2015.2**, negative scores are read as: "Minus {score}".  I don't have JAWS, so I can't test with that.

Comment: OS X "Text to Speech" feature read negative scores as "Minus {score}" too.

Comment: You should point out in your question that doing so align the numbers. Which improve readability because it's easier for the eyes. Many reader don't realize it. Adding it will make them realize it. To me there is no doubt that it's an improvement, but also I won't be surprised to see to other stuff coming first before this one.

Comment: Considering that the hyphen-minus is commonly used in development to denote a negative number (at least in C++, C#, PHP, Javascript, RPG, COBOL...virtually every language I've touched) I would think that changing to an em-dash would be a bit off-putting.  It just doesn't look right in my opinion.

Comment: @Bardicer The OP's text is not an em dash. The minus character is a distinct character.

Comment: @MrLister My bad, I meant to say U+002D. I mixed up decimal and hexadecimal. Wish I can go back and edit my comment.

Comment: Additional reading: "[You're using that dash wrong](http://theweek.com/articles/460264/youre-using-that-dash-wrong)" on theweek.com.

Comment: I guess it goes back to "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" for me.  I don't typically go to a "symbols" menu to get a negative number when I'm writing code.  I don't have a "minus" key on my keyboard, although I do have two "hyphen-minus" keys.  I guess this is more of a regional thing?

Comment: @AXMIM It aligns the text in the example given by OP, sure, but that's not universal. In fact, if you look at the score of this post right now, you'll see that it is using the dash instead of the minus sign and it is very nicely aligned: [Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/grjJ7.png)... The only way you'll get perfect alignment (in my experience) is to use a monospaced font, which seems like overkill in a discussion about a single character.

Comment: @MageXy: the image you show does not make your point. The `-10` is very clearly narrower than the `+76`. Also, in most commonly used fonts, the *digits* are 'tabular lining', that is, they are all equal width, and the `+` and minus are as well. The number of signs and the number of digits above and below are the same, so they should align. No need for monospaced text at all.

Comment: @MageXy I can't follow your argument. Look at the image in the post for how well aligned it looks with the correct minus sign. After all, that's the character that is intended to be used for this purpose.

Comment: U+002D isn't a dash. It's a compromise between two glyphs (hyphen and minus), neither of which is a dash.

Comment: People do dash over those signs lately! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317857/typo-on-the-mcve-page

Comment: BTW: Why can't I see the "+" on this question's score? See - http://i.imgur.com/SrbiZXj.png

Comment: @Abhitalks looks like it gets lost when the scores goes in the triple digits. If you click on Raedwald's score you still see it.

Comment: People are favoring this question? Oh wow. Wooow....

Comment: Why have any signs at all? green is positive red is negative. Well at least in some cultures.

Comment: @BSMP The screen reading software I use actually prefers the "wrong" character. It literally says "minus four". Using the proposed fix, it says "Minus sign four" which  doesn't seem like an improvement.

Comment: *"Minus sign four" which doesn't seem like an improvement* @vcsjones - Yeah, that does sound weird. I'd be like the screen reader reading the previous sentence as "Yeah comma that does sound weird period".

Comment: @AshleyMedway because not everyone can see the difference between green and read. And for that matter, not everyone can see, hence they have screen readers.

Comment: @zero298 The most recent thing I could find on how JAWS reads symbols is from 2014: http://www.deque.com/blog/dont-screen-readers-read-whats-screen-part-1-punctuation-typographic-symbols/  According to this, JAWS doesn't recognize the minus symbol *at all*. Hopefully that's been fixed by now.

Comment: I'm torn between having good UX for screen readers as they seem to behave _today_ and using the proper Unicode symbol in the way it _should be_.  It takes me back to the days when the Web was "designed for" either Netscape or IE.  (Thankfully the standards eventually won.)

Comment: Waiting for Jeff to come by and hit you with a large −.

Comment: Why the heck is a post about a teensy weeny little line beside furious, red down votes getting 163 up votes? Boy is Stack Overflow... well... weird.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Do you expect a site for programmers to not be full of nitpickers?

Comment: Hmm... I can't wait for Jeff to come by and hit everything with a giant **−**

Comment: This gets lots of upvotes?  And my request to fix another hyphenation error that actually caused confusion got downvoted?  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309426/non-community-wiki-answers-and-grammar      *whine whine*

Comment: @Joal 'tis a silly place. Someone went through my top posts and downvoted the first few after I posted this.

Comment: @Magisch Literally nitpicking? You're saying FUZxxl is combing through your hair and removing head lice? Gross.

Comment: I copied the fancy −4 from the question, pasted it in Notepad into some JavaScript code where a simple -4 would have worked, and got an "invalid character" error, whatever encoding setting I used when saving the file. So the support isn't quite universal.

Comment: I see you didn't use a typographically correct ligature in the word "prefix". You barbarian ...  look at that dot over the i, horribly distinct from the curl of the f.

Comment: Should this be migrated to StackExchange meta? It seems this change, if it happens, should be network wide.

Comment: @Kaz Ligatures are supposed to be used automatically by the typeface you selected. The Unicode committee decided not to add any more ligatures to Unicode for that reason. All existing ligatures exist for compatibility reasons only.

Comment: @m69 Tell me, how often are you going to do that in reality?

Comment: @FUZxxl It's just a simple example to demonstrate that the minus isn't universally recognised. Screen readers are the obvious example, but any kind of content scraping for any reason (including legitimate reasons) may trip over the minus character.

Comment: @m69 Content scrapers are the user group I'm least concerned about. Even then, the API is still going to deliver scores in JSON numeric representation, and the database dump is unaffected, so why does that matter?

Comment: The minus 3 probably made people giggle in a really childish way. Not me though. kjsjhhg

Comment: To @AshleyMedway 's point, how about using the accounting standard.  Not just red and green, but negative numbers in a parenthesis, such as `1` and `(3)`.

Comment: Can someone just [decide if SO are using hyphens or minuses!?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317857/typo-on-the-mcve-page?lq=1)

Comment: @WilliamPrice - When I said we should change it if it'd improve things for screen readers, I wasn't expecting to find out that the "correct" symbol would actually be worse! I figured the worst case scenario would be that it wouldn't improve anything. I don't think it's worth being typographically correct if it actually hurts user experience.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, @BSMP -- accessibility trumps typography, practically speaking. My standards-compliantness nerve still twitches because of the compromise and the inability to use the proper symbol (e.g. to be more specific than the dual-use _hyphen-minus_) until the screen readers add better support.  Though, as we saw with the Web, there's no reason to add better support until there's enough demand/use out in the real world.

Comment: What is "typographically correct"? How do you even define that? Is there a standard somewhere?

Comment: @jpmc26: now you must have given in to just being argumentative. Typographic rules have been honed to its current state in the past 500 years. Do you need *quotes*, from authoritative sources? Then you'd simply claim those are not sources you know and love. Here is one nevertheless:  [Typeset negative numbers in math mode. This will give them the proper minus signs they deserve. Hyphens are too short.](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/~kohler/latex.html#negative)

Comment: @jpmc26 See also D. Knuth *The TeXbook,* page 4 for a discussion about the difference between -, –, —, and −.

Comment: .. also (Wikipedia, so you'll probably brush it off) on the hyphen, "It can be used as a substitute for the true minus sign when the character set is limited to ASCII." We all know Stack Overflow is not 'limited to ASCII".

Comment: @RadLexus Thank you for the source. Your assertion that I'm being argumentative is incorrect, though. I considered this a major unclear point of the question, since without *some* kind of standard to go by, any form of "correct" is opinion based. That's why I commented on the question, not just in the answer. I expect most people probably don't know about the TeX background, so this would be useful to add to the question.

Comment: @jpmc26 TeX only implements the existing typographic conventions. It gets tiring trying to argue with people who have clearly absolutely no idea about typography and don't want to bother doing a simple five minute research on the subject matter either.

Comment: @jpmc26: Donald Knuth's development of *TeX* is an example of *how it should be done*. He set out to devise a language to typeset formulae with - and he considered typesetting them "properly" important enough to make a full study of the art of typesetting. Since plain TeX users probably would not be bothered to manually do so, he built many of these advanced rules "in" into TeX.

Comment: @FUZxxl I would argue that information that is not widely known should be presented/referenced so that it is readily available to your readers. This is standard on SO: present your information to help everyone understand where you're coming from. I am completely unfamiliar with the subject, so "5 minutes" would likely not bring me to the point where we're even close to the same page; that would more likely be a several hour or day effort. It's reasonable to ask that you to shorten that effort; as the requester of a change, it is partly your responsibility to provide evidence of its value.

Comment: If you don't do it on the first revision of your question, that's fine, but when someone asks for clarification, answer them instead of insulting them for not knowing. My tone probably is overly aggressive. I apologize, but I believe my question is valid.

Comment: @jpmc26 Such presentation exists, it's called a “library.” You might want to go there and check out a copy of the TeXbook. Or simply buy it. Or look at [the TeX source](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/knuth/dist/tex/texbook.tex)

Comment: @FUZxxl As I said, this is a several hour effort (at least), and it's unreasonable for you to demand every reader spend that much time to justify your change request for you. You seem to be knowledgeable on the subject. Why not present a summary of the relevant information in the question? Why does this matter? I don't have an answer for that, and I don't have hours or days to find it. If you have an answer, it would greatly strengthen your request *for all readers*, not just me.

Comment: Also, multiple users thought this was about alignment; this suggests your reasons are not clear from your question.

Comment: @jpmc26 It takes you several hours to read the page I cited? You surely are a slow reader. But anyway, I believe I did my duty in explaining the situation as good as possible. There isn't more in it than “- is not the right character to represent a minus sign.” I even provided references on request. I don't think I need to provide a full-fledged introduction to typography just so you can participate in the discussion without doing your own research. Also, I never mentioned alignment. I even clarified that it's not about alignment.

Comment: I don't have any form of TeX installed, so I'm stuck digging through source code trying to find information. Printing it to PDF results in 454 pages. A brief search turns up no actual advantages of using different symbols, only that "good math books" do it, not why. This also seems to be TeX specific, laying out how TeX should render the code, so it's not clear how it relates to an HTML page. So yes, it would take quite some time to sort out what info is relevant. Those 5 minutes seem to be spent. Not to mention SO discourages link only content; we're supposed to bring a summary in.

Comment: @jpmc26 You could buy a PDF render of the document on Amazon or a bookshop of choice. Or you could go to a library. There are more resources than the internet and it's not my job to spoon-feed you this information. I have provided a summary of the most important information. More is not required to understand the problem.

Comment: Actually, when you're asking somebody to do something for you, yes, it is your job to spoon-feed them the information they need to understand your justification. It is not other people's jobs to justify *your* request. It's yours. This is the essence of a good question on SO: it's simple to dive in and start understanding the context and the nature of the problem. Then readers can use that information to provide a useful response back.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not asking you to do anything. I have justified my feature request. What justification is missing? I have provided you with an authoritive source for my claim that - is not the right character to represent negation. If you refuse to read the source I gave you, that's not my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105407/discussion-between-jpmc26-and-fuzxxl).

Comment: I had no idea that there was even a specific "minus sign" character, and I was living just fine with the hyphen.  Now, I must say that I am bothered by the technical incorrectness.  Thanks a lot...

Comment: Just noticed that the [user profile and achievements dropdown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321748/4151918) don't use the same character for their -2.

Comment: @PetahChristian Wow, that's interesting.

Comment: MINUS SIGN (−) looks better to me. and it's semantically better.

Comment: Stack Overflow (now?) has a [style guide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_guide) of sorts: The *[Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/)* "[design system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_system)". But I don't think they go into such details. But I could be wrong. For instance, there is [a typography section](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/typography/) and the *"[Grammar and mechanics](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/)"* section (example: *"“OK” should be fully capitalized in every context."*).

Comment: From *[The Chicago Manual of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style)* 6.81: *"The en dash is sometimes used as a minus sign, but minus sign and en dashes are distinct characters (defined by the Unicode standard as U+2212 and U+2213, respectively) ... it is best to use the correct character"*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This strikes me as an *astoundingly* frivolous feature-request (and no, I don't consider it a bug).

I eagerly await the related request to [change the character required to search for negatively-scored posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:answer%20score:..-1).

Also on the edge of my seat waiting for the Kickstarter to fund a keyboard with your fancy Unicode minus sign in place of the normal one.

...Also, how could you have overlooked the existence of U+2796, the **heavy** minus sign! Downvoting is **important** and deserves **emphasis** - if we're gonna go clogging up the markup with weird, exotic symbols, it should be for a good cause - to *slap folks in the faces with the magnitude of their wrongitude*.

Compare, minus sign:

[image]

**Heavy** minus sign:

[image]

The choice is **clear.**

Comment: The popularity of this question is a very good example of [Parkinson's Law of Triviality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality).

Comment: Making the search function still yield the expected result isn't going to be a problem if my model of how Stack Overflow works is correct. After all, I'm only asking that the representation of a signed integer is changed in a single place. I'm not asking that Stack Overflow is delivering JSON with − instead of - to describe negative numbers, I'm merely asking that the way the score is displayed is changed.

Comment: @PeterOlson I was about to post that but it was so trivial... :P

Comment: I called out the triviality of captializing the "P" in "Possible duplicate", but was downvoted like crazy and the change went through.  People like their triviality.

Comment: I still resent that change.

Comment: How about using the hyphen for -0 to -5, the minus sign from -6 to -10, and the heavy minus sign from -11 to -infinity? Then the size actually does indicate the magnitude of wrongness!

Comment: Stack Overflow: *\*slap folks in the faces with the magnitude of their wrongitude\**

Comment: @Shog9 and you thought my FR about the review text was frivolous and nitpicky.

Comment: Is Jeff going to switch to a giant - and beat the OP with it?

Comment: If it wasn't Shog9, I'd say this post is condescending. So I guess it is.

Comment: I wish I could bounty this.

Comment: How can I possibly be condescending here, @Andras? I've clearly been using the wrong math symbol for like 20 years; pretty sure that makes me literally a philistine.

Comment: This was requested a long time ago for similar reasons and rejected for similar reasons. Might have been in the uservoice days.. everything old is new again!

Comment: Hypen should be deprecated as an arithmetic operator in **Python 4.0!** Who's with me.

Comment: Accepting this as that's the resolution of the feature request. However much I disagree with it.

Comment: “Also on the edge of my seat waiting for the Kickstarter to fund a keyboard with your fancy Unicode minus sign in place of the normal one.” — this but unironically.

Comment: The rephrasing of that as “We intentionally use the dash, otherwise users to have to type in the Unicode minus sign in place of the normal one, something keyboards don't currently support.” is a falsehood. This feature request only affects what the Stack Exchange software displays, not user input. (By the way: Markdown allows writing the character as `&minus;`. Still more than one keystroke, but not actually all that inconvenient. So even the decreased usability part is also false.)

Comment: People routinely copy output as input for logically equivalent values, @user3840170. Typographically-correct is great - when typesetting is the goal. But foolish fixation on typographical symbols in other contexts leads to little gain and much pain; it's been only a short while since the last time a colleague wasted time trying to figure out why example code didn't work, only to realize that it had been composed on a Mac and the meaning of its quotes lost. For a list of sites where mathematical typography is helpful, supported and often-used, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216606

Comment: Let's not completely remove the tone and tongue-in-cheek sarcasm the original author intended... The answer is quite darn old, hasn't been a problem in that time, and frankly, isn't even offensive.

Answer (score 143):

It should be corrected to use the minus sign `−` instead of `-`:

- To improve typographical correctness;
- And to correct the alignment of the digits on the upvotes and the downvotes.

Using CSS is not an alternative. Fonts will ensure that the minus sign is, by its definition, the same width as the plus sign; but a CSS approach will fail for those cases where a user style-sheet overrides Stack Overflow's stylesheet.

Comment: Note: This is not about alignment. I agree that alignment looks better with the proper symbol, but it's about using an actual minus sign in the first place.

Comment: Yes, @FUZxxl , thank you, that was oversight from me.

Comment: @FUZxxl the only reason I agree with using the minus comes down to alignment.

Comment: @FUZxxl: The [`-` symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) can be used both for minus and hyphen. Yes, it's only a compromise, but it's not *wrong*.

Comment: @Bergi That's for compatibility reasons. Typographically it is wrong. And that's all that matters.

Comment: When FUZxxl wrote "this is not about alignment", he meant the question. And he's right, the question is not about alignment. So, the original start of the answer (`It should be alligned:`) was wrong, and I corrected it. I think the other comments are misplaced in this answer.

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know that you could close a meta question as “primarily opinion based.”

Comment: "*And to correct the alignment of the upvotes with the downvotes*" -- How would you then get double-digit upvotes aligned with single-digit downvotes? Heck, the [triple-digit scores don't even show the symbol anyway](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317907/negative-question-scores-should-be-prefixed-with-a-%e2%88%92-minus-sign-instead-of-a#comment315379_317907)!

Answer (score 30):

Dashes vs hyphens vs minus in HTML5 Speech. I doubt this is actually specified

PS: Only works in Safari and Chrome AFAIK

PPS: I'm not voting. Just passing on info

```js
const signs = [
  ['hyphen-minus', '\u002d'],
  ['hyphen', '\u2010'],
  ['non-breaking hyphen', '\u2011'],
  ['figure dash', '\u2012'],
  ['en dash', '\u2013'],
  ['em dash', '\u2014'],
  ['horizontal bar', '\u2015'],
  ['hyphen bullet', '\u2043'],
  ['minus', '\u2212'],
  ['two-em dash', '\u2e3a'],
  ['three-em dash', '\u2e3b'],
];

document.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  const button = ev.target.closest('button');
  if (!button) return;
  const { name, sign } = button.dataset;
  const msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  msg.voiceURI = 'native';
  msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
  msg.lang = 'en-US';
  msg.text = `
    Let's try ${name}:
    Value = ${sign}1.
    See document number 69X${sign}420.
    The Y coordinate equals 69X${sign}420.
  `;
  speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
});

for (const [name, sign] of signs) {
  const node = document.createElement('button');
  node.dataset.name = name;
  node.dataset.sign = sign;
  if (sign === '\u2212')
    node.className = 'should';
  else if (sign === '\u002d')
    node.className = 'maybe';
  node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${name} (${sign})`));
  document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
  document.body.appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
body { line-height: 200%; }
button { background: maroon; color: white; }
button.should { background: green; }
button.maybe { background: olive; }
```

Comment: For me, on Chrome 48, with the minus symbol, it speaks "Value equals one".

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Chrome 49 as well.

Comment: Firefox 44 on Windows at work, with the latest version of JAWS (trial) installed: said "minus one" for both.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 48 too, but for both the dash and minus it said "value equals negative one".

Comment: on OSX Chrome it says "minus 1" for dash and "minus sign 1" for minus

Comment: On Chrome 49.0.2623.75 on Linux, it speaks "minus 1" for both.

Comment: I got "negative one" for both on Chrome 49.0.2623.87 m on Windows 7.

Comment: Firefox 48 (Linux) says “one” for `-1` and “minus one” for `−1`.

Comment: It's speaks "minus one" for both cases here / Chrome 54.0.2840.100 on Linux (RHEL 7.2)

Comment: Still not working for me in Windows 10 Chrome 70.0.3528.0.

I've filed a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=875978

Comment: At some point they required a user gesture to make sounds and finally added the same restriction here. Updated to fix it.

Comment: I replaced the snippet with a version that does not misname the characters. (The ‘dash’ was actually a hyphen.)

Answer (score 29):

First of all, the question is deceptively worded, since U+002D is called *hyphen-minus*, not *dash*. Which dilutes the strength of the argument considerably.

(Yes, the title was edited to say "hyphen" instead of "dash", which is an improvement; but it still feels slightly evasive, and the illustrative example still says "dash".)

I am sympathetic to the idea that "minus sign" (U+2212) *might* be the most semantically appropriate choice. I'm also sympathetic to the idea that typographical alignment is generally desirable.

If U+2212 consistently improved screen-reader results versus U+002D, that would be enough to sway me into the U+2212 camp. As it stands, the results suggest U+2212 is not a clear improvement on this front, and could actually make things worse.

On balance, I think hyphen-minus is semantically and aesthetically "right enough" that it's not worth changing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a native speaker. I thought - was called *dash* until I researched the name further, thus the edit.

Comment: @FUZxxl It *is* called a dash. It's also called a hyphen. It's the Unicode specification that gives this particular symbol the name "hyphen-minus".

Comment: @jpmc26: Well, it all depends on how loose you want to be with the terminology. You could argue that a hyphen is a kind of dash. But that isn't how a typographer would talk about it, especially when just using the term *dash* by itself, with no other context, implies something very different. FUZxxl and others have been making arguments based on either typography or semantics, and the **whole point** of the Unicode name is to identify glyphs as what they are "meant" to be. Otherwise any number of horizontal line glyphs would work equally well here.

Comment: U+002D ([HYPHEN-MINUS](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=40&number=128)). UTF-8 0x2D.

Answer (score 19):

The fate of the true typographic dashes was sealed in the late nineteenth century when typewriter manufacturers used the jack-of-all trades hyphen-minus on their too-crowded keyboards. Then the battle for computer typography was lost in the early 1960s, when ASCII put only a hyphen in their character set.

Comment: But now we have Unicode. Why does it matter that ASCII doesn't have a proper minus sign? It's not that I demand you type it in all the time.

Comment: @Raedwald By this argument, curly quotes have lost the battle too, right?

Comment: I'm quite sure @Raedwald was just joking. +1 for advanced sense of humour!

Comment: −1 for false pessimism

Comment: @anatolyg +1 for correct  −1.

Comment: @Raedwald, mind Poe's Law: «without a clear indicator of the author's intent, parodies of extreme views will be mistaken by some readers or viewers for sincere expressions of the parodied views.»

Comment: dang.. this answer... looks so calm at 0 score but its +30/-30.

Comment: @MrLister What, your keyboard has a `l` key?  Nifty!  Where do they put it?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ - How do you check that?

Comment: @praroh1 There's a privilege which allows you to see the breakdown of votes : Established user : http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @praroh1 [“View Vote totals” without 1000 rep](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)

Comment: My comment's obsolete now.... It's +73/-52 .... still controversial.

Comment: @FUZxxl "Now we have Uncidoe" Pfffffft. Unicode is a *mess*. Things are certainly better than they used to be for large character sets, but things are far from smoothed out. Try [this](https://eev.ee/blog/2015/09/12/dark-corners-of-unicode/), for instance. (His examples of things *going wrong* don't even *render incorrectly*, as the text indicates they should, in my browser.) Additionally, the adoption is nowhere near widespread; there's a ton of new code churned out every day with improper Unicode handling. (Heck, I bet both *you and I* are guilty of it.)

Answer (score 3):

A while ago, I wrote a [user script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362147/620615) to replace hyphens in front of negative scores with minus signs.  It works pretty great: no perceptible slowdowns, no re-layouting or flickering, the minus signs show up instantly as if they were there from the beginning, even in dynamic content.  The biggest drawback is that it kind of makes me cringe now every time I open Stack Exchange in a mobile browser, where I cannot install user scripts.

But honestly, I shouldn’t have had to do it.  It would have been much more fitting to do it in the Stack Exchange software proper, where each place where a negative value may be displayed is easily found, instead of condemning authors of user script workarounds to playing scraping whack-a-mole.

It’s not the 1960s any more, where one had to squeeze distinct characters together to avoid running out of typewriter keys or code points in an 8-bit code page.  Unicode exists now, support for it is ubiquitous, it has separate code points for each kind of horizontal line, so use them as intended!  If Stack Exchange are so convinced that hyphens are superior to actual minus signs, why not remove the latter from the Achievements pop-up menu, where they appear without me having to install any user scripts?

[image: Achievments popup, using minus signs]

Some have voiced the argument that screen readers may be unable to read minus signs correctly.  I don’t find it particularly persuasive.  If there are still any screen readers that are unable to recognise a real minus sign for what it is, they are broken and should be fixed instead of appeased, thereby perpetuating the vicious cycle of incompatibility (no author uses this, therefore no reader software supports this for lack of popularity, therefore no author uses this for fear of incompatibility, therefore…).  In fact, it should be *easier* for screen readers to read a minus sign code point correctly, because its meaning is unambiguous; the reader software can avoid applying fallible heuristics to guess whether the `-` character was meant as a hyphen, minus, or a dash.  The speech synthesiser in my crappy 10-year-old Samsung phone that runs out of memory on a regular basis reads minus signs just fine.  Are there really that many that can’t read them at all?

Answer (score -11):

No. A hyphen can be encoded in ASCII and therefore represents the optimal for compatibility. The idea that, "We have Unicode now," solves everything is absurd. Unicode certainly improves the situation for non-English character sets, but it far from solves it. See [this](https://eev.ee/blog/2015/09/12/dark-corners-of-unicode/) for some evidence of just how complicated this all is.

Additionally, I don't see any real problems this would solve, even though I do see a potential for *creating* compatibility problems. How about *accessibility*; do you know how it affects that? As a developer, this seems like a step backwards. The existing hyphen works, it is sufficiently visually appealing, and it's simple.

I simply *do not care* about a purely graphical problem that has zero practical impact. It does not interfere with my, and I am fairly certain anyone's, ability to understand the content. This is pedantic in the extreme.

Please leave it alone.

Comment: I simply *do not care* whether it's encodable in ASCII or not.

Comment: Welcome to the 21st century! We support Unicode by now. And no, you don't even need Unicode. That's why HTML4 has `&minus;` to represent the − character.

Comment: @FUZxxl You clearly didn't read the link I gave you on the other answer.

Comment: @Almo Except you should. A trivial graphical appearance issue is objectively better than a broken screen reader, or any other kind of broken code.

Comment: It's not trivial really. It makes the site look more professional. Typography is very important.

Comment: @Almo Breaking people's ability to interact with the site is a heck of a lot less professional. If it took 5 years for someone to make an issue of it, then yes, it's trivial.

Comment: FUZxxl already addressed the ASCII issue.

Comment: @Almo I'll repeat this since it was on another answer: "Now we have Uncidoe" Pfffffft. Unicode is a mess. Things are certainly better than they used to be for large character sets, but things are far from smoothed out. Try [this](https://eev.ee/blog/2015/09/12/dark-corners-of-unicode), for instance. (His examples of things going wrong don't even render incorrectly, as the text indicates they should, in my browser.) Additionally, the adoption is nowhere near widespread; there's a ton of new code churned out every day with improper Unicode handling. (Heck, I bet both you and I are guilty of it.)

Comment: @jpmc26 You don't even need Unicode to support using the proper minus. That's why HTML4 has `&minus;`.

Comment: @jpmc26: Re "took five years" -- unfortunately, in a system as complex as SE, we find glitches that have been around for years *all the time*. Are all of these simply never worth fixing? How about old questions? Should we write those off as never worth closing if no one noticed them before now? Old answers that have a weird little typo, should those not be edited? Please drop that particular argument; it detracts from any point you might have.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I can be more explicit if you insist: This has been *highly visible* for 5 years, and no one complained. It is literally on every page that has a downvote. Clearly this means that it has no significant impact. Please don't misrepresent other people's arguments.

Comment: @jpmc26: So, it wasn't noticed until it was noticed. That's kind of my point. The fact that it's apparently extremely subtle (but, once seen, cannot be unseen) is not much of an argument to avoid fixing it, but trying to argue on the basis of time is even less of one. Either it doesn't matter (in which case what is that 250+ score doing?) or it does; the amount of time it's been around before being noticed is a very, very poor proxy for importance.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Guess you'll be asking for alignment of zeros next, then. I'm sorry, but it's  completely reasonable to ask someone to get over something this minor.

Comment: @jpmc26: Sure, why not. If it makes things look better, it makes them better. There's no such thing as an edit that's too minor.

Answer (score -13):

I respectfully disagree that the typographer's minus sign should be used in place of the programmer's hyphen.  My reason: this is a community for programmers, not typographers. The computer languages in daily use all use hyphens to indicate negation.

To switch to another codepoint for this purpose would be favoring styling at the expense of semantics.

Comment: Semantically, the minus sign, not the hyphen is correct.

Comment: SO *does* care about "pure styling": [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286313/2564301) tells me all text on the site is kerned. It's a purely typographical decision to do (or don't do) this; I know of no programming language where kerning is important.

Comment: My point is this: for programmers and the languages we use, negation is indicated by the ASCII hyphen code point, not the Unicode minus code point. It would be a disaster if the questions and answers on SO had the hyphens changed to minus signs for the sake of styling. (I know you're not suggesting that.)

Comment: @OllieJones If I'm not suggesting that, why are you even raising this point? Sounds like a strawman to me.

Comment: @RadLexus no, that screenshot shows that they just stick to the default kerning. The faded out properties (everything except family, size, and weight for that particular element) are all inherited from the browser

Comment: The argument doesn't hold water. If we wanted SO to be slavishly faithful to what programmers write when we're coding, then all the questions and answers should be displayed in Courier or some other fixed-pitch font. After all, that's what I see in my IDE. Personally, I'm glad that SO opts for more readable than my IDE, and I think OP's suggestion would be an improvement (albeit by only a tiny bit).

Comment: @OllieJones: Oh, you mean the way quotes in titles are changed to curly quotes? That would indeed be unfortunate, but so far we've muddled through without any worse auto-obfuscation.

Comment: I mentioned this in [a comment on another answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317907/negative-question-scores-should-be-prefixed-with-a-%E2%88%92-minus-sign-instead-of-a/317974?noredirect=1#comment315406_317974), but it applies equally well to yours, more so since it's your _entire_ answer - this change could well apply network wide, not just here on Stack Overflow - ie there are others than just programmers who would see it/be affected.

Comment: Everything in proper typography is to smooth the experience of reading and taking in information. This site is all about making information easier to get.

Comment: @OllieJones I agree with you, but mostly in the sense that the whole argument is absolutely absurd. The minus sign does not appear on the keyboard, even on the right number pad because the hyphen is used interchangeably as a minus sign. It is possible that many programming languages would not accept a "minus sign", but the main absurdity is that apart from screen readers and encoding errors, there is no significance to the underlying bytes that are used to encode a particular symbol. It is literally just a line of chosen width. The only valid question then is the desired length of the symbol.

Comment: Additionally, it only has significance of alignment when a + sign is used above it. In other places, a dash may be better for alignment.

Comment: We are programmers and we type, so we also need to be typographers.
We came here to read AND to lead, so we have to be correct professionally, not politically.

Answer (score -16):

This is pedantic. It doesn't even work.

You get misalignment when the number of digits don't match:

[image: +9 and -18 don't line up]

Or when only one of the up/down vote counts is zero, which has no sign:

[image: zero doesn't line up with +1]

Are you going to insist these line up, too? Changing the sign doesn't help them. I'm afraid you're simply going to have to deal with some misalignment, no matter what changes are made. Even if we "align" the above, how would we do it? Right align? Left align? Whether either of those is better than center aligned is a matter of complete opinion.

Just leave it alone. The risk of breaking things like accessibility outweighs any small satisfaction you might receive from them lining up. Don't be [this guy](https://xkcd.com/1271/) or [these guys](https://xkcd.com/915/).

(I'm posting this as a new answer because I believe the content differs significantly enough from my [other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318131/1394393) that people might vote differently on it.)

Comment: Note that it was another answer that brought up the advantages of alignment; the question does not mention it. (I support aligning too, but let's keep things organized, eh?)

Comment: @NathanTuggy In a sense, you're correct. However, it points out a glaring problem with the request itself: there is no analysis of benefits or downsides in the question at all. So we're left to make our own guesses. I can only assume "typographically correct" means they believe it to be more visually appealing, and the only reason I can think of for that is alignment (which is the only notable difference in the example images). If you have some other benefit to argue for (whether in the question itself or not), please let me know.

Comment: @jpmc26: "typographically correct" is a reason on itself; much like editing a post to be "grammatically correct" is a reason on itself and does not need any further defending.

Comment: @RadLexus I am not aware of any accepted standard definition of "typographically correct." Could you point to one, and preferably to the section that states the hypen-minus Unicode character is somehow an invalid choice for a numeric negative sign? Language, including grammar, symbols, mechanics, and anything else is purely conventions and evolves over time. The "wrongness" of this symbol is completely unestablished, as far as I know.

Comment: If alignment is an issue, then we'll also have to start thinking in using monospaced typefaces when using numbers and also add leading blank spaces to have the best perspective of statistical data, plus to issues regarding [long numbers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148048/should-the-network-use-thousands-separators-in-numbers).