# Is there any info on C-​- on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, search

I am trying to find some questions or wikis related to the **C--** programming language. However, when I type `C--` in the search box, I get `C++` questions instead. I am curious if there really isn't even a single question related to C--, which would surprise me, or is it just a search algorithm problem?

References:

- [C-- Home page](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/c--/)
- [C-- on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C--)
- [C-- on GitHub](https://github.com/nrnrnr/qc--)

Comment: just found this tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-minus-minus

Comment: You may write that as an answer.

Comment: discussed at MSE: [Ability to search for C--](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148718/165773)

Comment: I swear, I thought C-- was just a Jontron joke.

Comment: Maybe we should have a feature request to alter the tag to go along with this [score request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317907/1195056).

Comment: he `C--`. what's this? first time hear this

Answer (score 53, accepted):

C-- isn't very popular on Stack Overflow, but is definitely on topic - there's a [c-minus-minus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-minus-minus) tag with four questions.

For why the tag label text is `c-minus-minus` rather than the more intuitive `c--`, see: [Ability to search for C--](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148718/ability-to-search-for-c), which also explains why many C-- questions may have been mistagged as [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), and proposes a [SymbolHound search](http://symbolhound.com/?q=c--&u=stackoverflow.com) as an alternative to using the search box here on Stack Overflow in this particular case.

Comment: Yep, even the [Forth tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forth) is more popular.

Comment: I'm still not clear on why the tag is "c-minus-minus" instead of "c--", especially considering the C++ tag is "c++" and not "c-plus-plus"

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with syntax?  Maybe because of the `-` separating words within tags?  So `c----`

Comment: Exceptional the link to SymbolHound! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CaptainHypertext silly, you cannot post-decrement twice.

Comment: Now you may search for `"C--"` in quotes -- see the linked mse q&a