# When comparing upvotes to downvotes, the minus is missing on numbers above 100

Tags: bug, downvotes, voting, upvotes

I just noticed a display inconsistency :

When looking at details of upvotes VS downvotes, I noticed that the minus sign is not always displayed.

The pattern I noticed is that the minus sign is *displayed* if the downvotes number is 1 or 2 digits long, *not displayed* if larger.

[image: downvotes differences]

For a reproducible example, one can look at the [moderator election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election/10?tab=primary) (with 1000+ reputation)

EDIT : it seems the pattern is the same for '+' sign as well, as shown in a duplicate [SE Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230536/large-down-vote-count-doesnt-display-negative-sign).

[image]

Comment: It's definitely not a styling (CSS) issue, as the HTML is omitting the minus sign as well on these.

Comment: On MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/vote-split-does-not-include-leading-sign-when-count-exceeds-99 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230536/large-down-vote-count-doesnt-display-negative-sign

Comment: @Pang thank you for the links, didn't try to look on [meta.se] . The behaviour at least is consistent between + and - .

Comment: That is [not a minus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317907/2564301)!

Comment: I didn't initially read the question and I thought the inconsistency might have been colours, so I zoomed in and spent a good minute looking to later found out the colours weren't an issue

Comment: An alternative feature request would be removing the plus and minus in all cases. (I wouldn't necessarily support such a change, though I feel it would have a better chance of succeeding, given the by-design status Jesse de Bruijne points out.)

Comment: The + isn't displayed either. This is legal.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: A number is understood to be positive when the sign is omitted. It is not understood to be negative when the sign is omitted. This is at worst _not_ legal, and at best very confusing.

Comment: Shoot, I clicked this subject line hoping to get a link to a SO question with at least 100 downvotes.   Because that would be impressive.

Comment: @TabAlleman here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519990/why-does-i-j-k-j-i-kk-i-j-11 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c

Comment: Note that the election page does not use the same UI as the Q&A pages, which [already handle 5 digits, with a `+`, and could easily handle 5 digits with a `-`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308186/148310).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it's red when negative, it's green when positive. But i kind of agree, some people have a color blindness, for them it would be hard to see the color, then again, the negatives are always below...

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: Having the colour is fine, and the positioning is also enough to indicate up vs down - but actually changing the sign of the number is not okay. Either have `-` in addition to the other cues, or don't, but pick one!

Comment: If you convert this to a [tag:feature-request], I will happily cast a reopen vote.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This looks like a design choice, not a bug, as explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/45498) on MSE:

> This is by design so the numbers fit more easily in the available space.

Comment: not sure if I should retag OP as a feature-request, even though it's probably doomed to be rejected as status-by-design as well.

Comment: That's really bad. They should drop the sign for the red text in all cases then.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, since a minus plus 3 digits fits just as well as 4 positive digits (which seems to be the typical scenario).

Comment: @BrockAdams Even if the minus is an order of magnitude higher than the plus, the current design has to account for [5 digits](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36656/most-upvoted-answers) anyway. May as well make it account for up to 6 digits, which would be plenty of room for a 5 digit negative number.

Comment: @jpmc26, Turns out that there are [currently no posts with anymore than low triple-digit downvotes anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308186/148310).