# Vote display minor bug: no + or - with three digit numbers

Tags: bug, voting

The "-" character doesn't appear if the vote count is three digits.

**Normal:**

[image]

**Bug:**

[image]

This also happens with the "+" character([this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination))

Comment: @duplode It is the same problem, but their question is focusing on elections. I'm not sure whether to mark it as a dupe.

Comment: Here is [a non-election duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364850/2751851).